# In Angular 10 is it possible to have different data for dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

Consider the below dynamic route:

```
export const routes: Routes = [ 
{  
    path: 'template/:templateId',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    data: { pageTitle: 'TEMPLATES'}
}]
```

Is it possible to have dynamic pageTitle for same route and same component ?

- Example:
- If URL is 'template/01' then I need to set pageTitle in data as 'TEMPLATES-01'.
- If URL is 'template/02' then I need to set pageTitle in data as 'TEMPLATES-02'.

In this scenario the path remains the same 'template/:templateId' component also remains same 'TemplateComponent' but the URL changes to 'template/01' and 'template/02'.

Comment: Maybe?: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title#use-the-title-service

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (as R. Richards indirectly pointed out) using the `Title` in `@angular/platform-browser`

You could do the change locally (in each component on initialization - ngOnInit, but that would be repetitive and changing every title - if needed, would become a time consuming job) or you could make a service in which you change the title of the page based on the ActiveRoute

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) could be a reasonable solution.
It could take the param of the ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
and return a title that matches the route from its resolve-function.

Usage for the route would be something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'template/:templateId',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    resolve: { pageTitle: TemplateResolveService },
}]
```